Highlight a certain category in React recharts
I'm trying to build a reusable chart component that will suit my needs for this project
Currently I'm having issues with doing the highlight bellow

The issue is those yellow-ish highlights are only possible to do the way I want them if I set the X axis to type number, but then the Issue will be another one when I do the same thing with months
I tried to set the
<ReferenceArea x1={2006} x2={2006} />
<ReferenceArea x1={2006} x2={2007} />

The only one that works is
<ReferenceArea x1={2006} x2={2008} />

But issue with this one is that it wouldn't be centered with the year.
Current code:

    const renderGraphComponent = (unit: YAxisKey<T>) => {
            return <Line {...unit} dataKey={unit.key} key={unit.key} dot={false} />;
         }

return (
        <ResponsiveContainer minWidth={1200} width={'100%'} height={'80%'}>
            <ComposedChart
                onMouseMove={handleTooltipPayload}
                data={[...data]}
                margin={{ right: 50 }}
            >
                {yAxisKeys.map(yAxis => renderGraphComponent(yAxis))}
                <Tooltip wrapperStyle={{ display: 'none' }} />
                <defs>
                    <LinearGradient defs={yAxisKeys} />
                </defs>
                <CartesianGrid vertical={false} stroke="#ccc" strokeDasharray="10 5" />
                <XAxis
                    tick={{ textAnchor: 'middle' }}
                    tickLine={false}
                    type="category"
                    tickMargin={10}
                    dataKey={String(xAxis)}
                />
                <YAxis type="number" tickLine={false} />
                <ReferenceArea
                    x1={2012}
                    x2={2014}
                />
            </ComposedChart>
        </ResponsiveContainer>
    );


When an XAxis is categorical, you can only go from category to category. A category cannot do interpolation because it has no concept of the items between it. i.e. 2006 is just "2006". It doesn't know that it is a time or a number that has things between it.
When the axis is numerical, we can do interpolation between numbers since we know that between 2006 and 2008 is 2007. That number still has no clue that 2006 is a year.
You could convert your time data into numerical milliseconds, and format it as needed in tickFormatter (if you need to interpolate months between the years in the same chart). Then however, your ticks and reference values would need to be specified as exacts (i.e. 2024/01/01 aka 2024 would be 1704096000000). You could get that info from the JS Date object given a year.
If your goal is to have a "month"-only chart similar to this "year"-only chart you could store months as numbers 01 - 12 and in tickFormatter map them to their corresponding display value using a date library or just an object.
const MONTHS = {
  1: 'Jan',
  2: 'Feb',
  3: 'March',
  ...etc.
}

...

<XAxis
  ...etc.
  // months you want to show
  ticks={[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]}
  // min, max
  domain={[1, 12]}
  type="number"
  // this is what will show in the chart
  tickFormatter={(value, i) => {
    // use a map or just use an array + index
    return MONTHS[value];
  }}
/>

Sandbox for the month example: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/line-chart-sof-question-qy6w4f
